# Use controller namespace from route closure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want a `Route::group()` to use a particular namespace using a closure rather than using the laravel syntax. So instead of

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'My\Namespace\For\Controllers'), function () {

     // TestController found in `My\Namespace\For\Controllers`
     Route::resource('resource/url', TestController@test)
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to have something like

```
Route::group(function () {

     // Some logic for using the `My\Namespace\For\Controllers` 
     // namespace for all routes within this group

     // Controller found in `My\Namespace\For\Controllers`
     Route::resource('resource/url', Controller@test)
}
```

I want this functionality so I can decide the controller name-space dynamically depending on a parameter passed to a route.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the right way to do that is to create middleware, but definetely not `route.php` file.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

**Update**

If you need just to set namespace for all controllers in a group, you can do it like this:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'My\Namespace\For\Controllers'], function() {
    // Controllers within the "My\Namespace\For\Controllers" namespace
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-namespaces

Comment: Good idea, I already use some custom middleware in my project. Would you care to elaborate on how to specify a controller namespace from middleware?

Comment: So, you just need to add namespace to all controllers? Then you can do it easier with standard Laravel namespace group. Please check updated answer.

Comment: I need to change the namespace depending on a parameter in the url. I can extract the parameter and build the namespace in the closure, I just don't know how to then apply that namespace to each controller within that group